# Why do I have to call .toClass() after changing a method body with Javassist?

Tags: java, javassist

I modify `getMessage()` method body of my `TestClass` by Javassist like this:

```
ClassPool cp = new ClassPool(true);
CtClass ctClass = cp.get("my.test.javassist.TestClass");
CtMethod ctMethod = ctClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMessage");
ctMethod.setBody("{ return \"Hello from javassist\"; }");
ctClass.toClass();

TestClass c = new TestClass();
System.out.println(c.getMessage());
```

It works well. However, if I remove the `ctClass.toClass()` method call, the body substitution doesn't work. Why?

How should I correctly replace the body of my `getMessage()` method? Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `ClassPool` contains `CtClass` objects - they represent classes but they are *not* java classes. The `toClass()` methods convert `CtClass` instances into java classes and actually load the class.

If you do not execute `toClass()`, then the byte code changes will not be compiled into the class and `new TestClass()` will trigger a classload from the classpath.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas_D. So the standard approach is to modify the `CtClass` objects and after all the modifications 'commit' the changes by calling `toClass()`, right?

Comment: @miso - that's my understanding :) And I'm pretty sure that we can't make changes *after* a class has been loaded. So it should fail if you create a `TestClass` instance *before* you call `toClass()`. Just because a JVM can't *reload* a class.

Comment: Actually, reloading parts of classes is possible using the debugger interfaces (Eclipse can change methods of existing objects, for example). I don't know whether Javassist supports this, though.

Comment: That's [HCR (Hot Code Replacement)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F), a special debugging technique (using different JVMs and the debugging channel)