# How to create a variable of a class that is created using javassist

Tags: java, javassist, fasterxml

I created a pojo class at runtime using javassist. I am trying to convert a XML file to java object using the pojo i created, using jackson mapper as shown below,

```
//test.proper.MyRuntimeClass is the Pojo I created using javassist.
CtClass ctClass = classPool.getCtClass("test.proper.MyRuntimeClass");

mapper.readValue(<InputStream>, Class.forName(ctClass.getName()));
```

I able to parse the XML file but, I am unable to assign a variable of type MyRuntimeClass to the above line.

I want something like this.

```
test.proper.MyRuntimeClass myClass = mapper.readValue(<InputStream>, Class.forName(ctClass.getName()));
```

Please let me know the proper way to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMO you are making life difficult for yourself doing this. Your "Runtime Class" is going to have no methods and nothing about it's "Class-iness" is going to be of value. I think it would be easier if you just use a Datatype collection, possibly a `Map`. Can you explain why you don't want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You cant use the class in "regular" java code. You need to compile "regular" java code, to be compilable a compiler needs all the bytecode of the classes it uses.

But you can get around that:

- Create an interface that the javassist generated class implements, and use that type for the variable "myClass"
- Generate the code that uses MyRuntimeClass with javasisst
- Use Object as type of "myClass" and reflection to access methods/properties on it.

In my opinion creating the interface is the easiest to write/understand/maintain approach

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the CtClass to a Class first. Then pass it to Mapper as the Class.

```
Class MyRuntimeClass = ctClass.toClass();
mapper.readValue(<InputStream>, MyRuntimeClass);
```

More details are here - 
[Why do I have to call .toClass() after changing a method body with Javassist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385789/why-do-i-have-to-call-toclass-after-changing-a-method-body-with-javassist)